# CMB2 file_list paginate (real pages) foreach uses serialized data

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, foreach, meta-boxes

I have a hard time giving up using [CMB2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2)  file_list field my gallery but it doesn't have the option (built in) to paginate (like ACF) and my php skills are lacking. I can do it with jQuery but **I want real pages**.

This is getting close to what I need and it's cobbled together from another question. It splits out 5 results from the $files (get_post_meta) and creates pages but the images are all the same images on all the pages. I am beyond the limit of my brain.

The **$attachment_id => $attachment_url** is the individual image from the ones selected from the Media Library.

```
$files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url
```

Here's what I have so far (you might want to ditch it in favor of something better):

```
function gallery_loop() {

if( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $page = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else {
    $page = 1;
}


$img_size = 'portfolio-catalog';


$files = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_cmb_gallery_images', true);
$limit = 5;
$total = count( $files );
$pages = ceil( $total / $limit );

$curr_page = isset($_GET['page']);
$offset = ($curr_page - 1) * $limit;


$items_array = array_chunk((array) $files, $limit, true); 

$files_array = array_slice($items_array, $offset, true); // this is showing the same 5 items on all the pages

foreach ($files_array as $files) {

    echo '<div style="border:1px solid red;">'; //BEGIN FAKE "page" so I can see if they are splitting correctly

    foreach ($files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url) {

    $page=1;

        echo '<div class="file-list-image">';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, $img_size);
        echo '</div>';

    $page++;


    } // end $files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url

    echo '</div>'; //END "page" so I can see if they are splitting correctly


} // end foreach $files_array as $files



//the correct amount of pages are showing up but the items are all the same
 echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => get_permalink() . '%#%' . '/',
    'format' => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => $page,
    'total' => $pages
  ) );


}
// end function
```

**Answer to questions in comments:**

This is for a page template called gallery-page.php. It is page that has a CMB2 field type called file_list and that is a place to attach images to (they are attached not to the page, but to that field so you can grab any and upload to it too).

When I do a print_r from `$files = get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , '_cmb_gallery_images', true);` I get:

```
Array( [956] => http://mydevserver.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/bamboo-logo.jpg [960] => http://mydevserver.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tampa_guitar_logo.jpg [958] => http://mydevserver.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/CNG-refueling.jpg [974] =>
```

and so forth.

Comment: Is this for a single page

Comment: as you have taken the images array from get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_cmb_gallery_images', true);
So either all the images needs to be used is in one single page or you have created the Gallery post type for that. Please clarify ?

Comment: So you are looping the function how? Assuming you want this for single page, you are calling `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_cmb_gallery_images', true)` which just gets the post meta of that page. When you do a `print_r($files);` right below defining the variable, what do you get out?

Comment: @dingo_d - I get all the urls to the images (here's what it looks like but there are more) : Array( [956] => http://christinacreativedesign.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/bamboo-logo.jpg [960] => http://christinacreativedesign.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tampa_guitar_logo.jpg [958] => http://christinacreativedesign.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/CNG-refueling.jpg [974] =>

Comment: @PieterGoosen  It's a page template in WordPress that has a CMB2 file_list type field where I can just attach to that field any image from the Media library (and upload) and then you can make a list of images on the page.

Comment: This has been answered, updates and awards coming later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code provided below, 5 images will be displayed per page, and pagination links will allow the user to navigate between the gallery’s pages at pretty URLS such as /gallery/2/, /gallery/3/ and so on.

```
function gallery_loop() {

    if (get_query_var('page')) {
        $page = get_query_var('page');
    }
    else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    //* variables   
    $row = 0;
    $images_per_page = 5; //image count
    $img_size = 'portfolio-catalog'; //image size
    $images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , '_cmb_gallery_images', true); //cmb2 field
    $total = count($images);
    $pages = ceil($total / $images_per_page);
    $min = (($page * $images_per_page) - $images_per_page) + 1;
    $max = ($min + $images_per_page) - 1;


    echo '<ul class="your-class clearfix">';

     //* create the 'pages'    
    if (count($images) > 0) {

       foreach ((array) $images as $attachment_id => $attachment_url ) {


            $row++;

            // ignore this image if $row is lower than $min
            if ($row < $min) {
                continue;
            }

            // stop loop completely if $row is higher than $max
            if ($row > $max) {
                break;
            }

            //echo the images
            echo '<li>';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, $img_size);
            echo '</li>';


        } //end foreach

         //* pagination
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_permalink() . '%#%' . '/',
            'format' => '?page=%#%',
            'current' => $page,
            'total' => $pages
        ));

    } else {

        echo '<li>No images found.</li>';

    } //endif;

    echo '</ul>';


} // end gallery_loop;
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising. I get this error `Undefined variable: metas in /...`

Comment: I didn't need the `get_meta_values`, I got it working and will post a gist in this thread. If you update your answer with the gist content, then I will mark this accepted. I wouldn't have been able to figure it out without you, so THANK YOU! It was bugging me even though I had no current project that required it, it will come in very handy.

Comment: Okay, I'm not ready for gist since I want to work out some other stuff that is not related to the question. Here is a jsbin, i stuck the php in the js field: https://jsbin.com/gabozu/js

Comment: Hey Christina . Thanks for the comments . I just want to know do you have one specific page in which you have added gallery images or is it a custom post type or in many pages ??

Comment: It's anywhere, in CMB2 you can specify what page template to use: `$cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
  'id'           => $prefix . 'cmb2_gallery',
  'title'        => __( 'Gallery', $GLOBALS['text-domain'] ),
        'object_types' => array( 'page' ), // post type
        'show_on'      => array( 'key' => 'page-template', 'value' => 'cmb2-gallery-page.php' ),
        'context'      => 'normal',
  'priority'     => 'default',
 ) );`

Comment: The jsbin works great. I have several galleries and so I create a page, choose the gallery page, save draft, then the field shows up, I load or select images from the library (no need for it to be attached to that page/post) and then all the images show up and then I reorder them. I have several other number field to choose how many per page and how many per row.

Comment: can u let me know what is the problem you are facing now .. as the code which you have at jsbin seems fine. Also are you getting the pagination links in bottom and if yes , then what is the URL when a page is clicked ?

Comment: The jsbin code is fine, but I want to award you the points, so if you just copy in the code in the bin into your answer, then I will award them. The question is answered and I wouldn't have been able to figure it out without you.

Comment: The SO system says I can award in 9 hours. So I will be back.

Comment: 4 more hours to go. Just last week I awarded immediately. This system is wacked.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that all of the data is actually in your corresponding vars. But anyway, could you please provide var_dump of $files after you set it from post_meta? (In case that my fast solution would not work)

Also, instead of array_slice you can use direct index of array element in foreach statement, but it's not important

```
foreach ($items_array[$curr_page - 1] as $files) {
```

Anyway, the main problem is here:

```
$curr_page = isset($_GET['page']);
```

isset is always returning true or false (1 or 0). So, despite of the page you're always loading first or second one. Just replace the code with:

```
$curr_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
```

Additionally, you can check your $_GET['page'] with is_int() or is_numeric() & round it ( just in case :D )